# Is it possible to put multiple card in the layout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I've read the example of how to use [Card Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) but it's still not clear if can put multiple cards in the same `JPanel` in a row. I mean something like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Not understanding what you want to do well, [`GridLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) may be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would nest containers (JPanels) each using its own layout, and thereby would effectively nest layouts. The outside JPanel could use `GridLayout(1, 3)` (one row, three columns), and it could hold 3 JPanels that each use CardLayout, each holding its own cards (JComponents).

Comment: @DmitriiBundin: it should, nested JPanels is how most real-world Swing applications are created.